# React-Native lifecycle : ComponentDidMount doesn't work after close the app and change the component

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I'm new in React Native and I have a bug in my code in the lifecycle.

The problem starts when I do this:

1. View Dashboard
2. Go to view Timer
3. Do some stuff on Timer in `componentDidMount()`
4. Close the app
5. Open the app (Welcome view) and go to Timer
6. Do some stuff on Timer
7. Go to Dashboard
8. Go to Timer Again and try do something in `componentDidMount() //Here's the error`

The problem when I go to Timer AFTER close the app is that the code inside `componentDidMount()` doesn't work. When I try the same without close the app everything it's ok, but when I close it the component doesn't "reload" or anything so I can't see any change.

The Timer it's just a view that loads and send data from a server and the Dashboard just has a button to go to Timer where send the data in `componentDidMount()`.

(I don't think that it's important but I'm using Expo)

So what I need it's when I close the app or whatever I do when I go to Timer the second time it calls a custom function in/out `componentDidMount`/`componentWillMount`, by now the second time the Timer and the function are frozen and don't do anything.

I know that probably there is a method that can resolve this but I would like to know the best way to do that.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

componentDidMount work only one time when component is loaded. Is your timer Component is unmounted when you are navigating to Dashboard as mentioned is point. If not then it will not be called again.
In order to resolve this either you need to unmount your component of use componentDidUpdate.